# Reference request: Trying to locate the reference of a quote by Pope Athanasius of Alexandria about the Trinity

Tags: trinity, reference-request, persons-of-the-trinity, athanasius

I read this quote for Saint Athanasius of Alexandria in an Arabic book, but I am trying to locate the source (reference) of that quote (in which work for Athanasius), or something of the similar meaning by the saint.

> "The Persons are not three gods, but rather they are one triune God
> with the consistency of His mind (the Father), His word (the Son), and
> His Spirit, who are the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit."

Comment: Highlighted text (as presented above) should only be used in conjunction with a certified source. The above does not represent the words of Athanasius.

Comment: Thanks for the note, as I mentioned that they are translated from Arabic, so I am not sure of the exact words, also that what I am asking.. for the "certified source". Do you think I should edit the question and remove the highlight of the quote? Also do you want the Arabic source?

Comment: My only concern is to reliably quote the words of Athanasius which words I greatly respect, remembering that our words are recorded publicly around the world.

Answer (score 2):

The quote that is closest to what you are looking for is found in the work *Quaestiones aliae* by Athanasius of Alexandria.

> Ὡς γὰρ ψυχὴ, λόγος καὶ πνοὴ τρία πρόσωπα, καὶ μία φύσις ψυχῆς, καὶ οὐ
> τρεῖς ψυχαί· οὕτω Πατὴρ, Λόγος καὶ Πνεῦμα ἅγιον, τρία πρόσωπα, καὶ εἷς
> τῇ φύσει Θεὸς, καὶ οὐ τρεῖς θεοί.

That can be translated as:

> For soul, word, and breath are three persons, and one nature of the
> soul, and not three souls; thus Father, Word, and Holy Spirit, three
> persons, and one nature of God, and not three gods.

However you can find similar phrases in other works such as *Symbolum quicumque* or *De sancta trinitat*

Comment: Thanks, yes it's a bit close, but I am trying to find where did the saint say that the "`father is the mind`", as I think that's not a genuine quote, or mistranslated

Comment: @Mike You are arguing without a source. The answer above quotes the source of the quotation and gives both the Latin and the English.

Comment: @Mike You must then correct your question. Because you really don't want to _locate the source of that quote (in which work for Athanasius), or **something of the similar meaning by the saint**_. But whether "father is the mind" is a genuine quote from the saint or just a translation error. The focus of your question should not be the quote, but the content of it.